# API Post request in Google App Script not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, post, urlfetch

I managed to do the API POST request through Postman but once modified for Google App Script it doesn't work. I think it might be related to the `body` format, I can't replicate the `new URLSearchParams()` object in GAS (I'm sending a JSON I believe).

Thanks.

Postman (working) - JavaScript Fetch

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("client_id", "XXXX");
urlencoded.append("client_secret", "XXXX");
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://apigateway.criteo.com/oauth2/token", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

CURL

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://apigateway.criteo.com/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=XXXX' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=XXXX' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

My faulty GAS version :(

```
function getCostAU() {
  
  var myHeaders = {"Accept": "application/json",
                   "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"};
  
  var myPayload = {"client_id" : "XXXX",
                   "client_secret" : "XXXX",
                   "grant_type" : "client_credentials"};
  
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: myPayload,
    redirect: 'follow',
  };
    
  var url = "https://apigateway.criteo.com/oauth2/token";
  var result = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions).getContentText());
  var access_token = result.access_token;
};
```

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks. You mean that the URLSearchParams() object can be replicated in GAS with a encodeURIComponent ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Issues:

- `body` is [not a valid key in `options` argument](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)). You should use `payload` instead.
- `redirect` is not a valid key in  `options` argument
- Currently, [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams#Examples) is not supported in apps script.

#### Solution:

- Change `body` to `payload`
- Re-create the `payload` object as a query string. For example, `payload:{x:1,y:2}` should be changed to `x=1&y=2`.

#### Snippet:

- Payload object to query params:

```js
function objectToQueryParams(obj) {
  return (
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([k, v]) => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`)
      .join('&')
  );
}

const myPayload = {"client_id" : "XXXX",
               "client_secret" : "XXXX",
               "grant_type" : "client_credentials"};
  
console.log(objectToQueryParams(myPayload));
```

- Valid `requestOption`:

```
  const requestOptions = {
    /**@see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)*/
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    payload: objectToQueryParams(myPayload),//modified
    //or just payload: myPayload will work as mentioned in the comments below
    //redirect: 'follow',//removed 
    followRedirects: true
  };
```

- Full script:

```js
/**Mock UrlFetchApp library*/
const UrlFetchApp = {
  fetch: () => ({
    getContentText: () =>
      '{"access_token":"jghlfdjlfwqwXjogsfshbkgetrwuguerjyrcyfxuux=="}',
  }),
};
getCostAU(); //call function
//Mock end


function getCostAU() {
  const myHeaders = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  };

  const myPayload = {
    client_id: 'XXXX',
    client_secret: 'XXXX',
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  };

  function objectToQueryParams(obj) {
    return Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([k, v]) => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`)
      .join('&');
  }

  const requestOptions = {
    /**@see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)*/
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    payload: objectToQueryParams(myPayload), //modified
    //or just payload: myPayload will work as mentioned in the comments below
    //redirect: 'follow',//removed
    followRedirects: true,
  };

  const url = 'https://apigateway.criteo.com/oauth2/token';
  const result = JSON.parse(
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions).getContentText()
  );
  const access_token = result.access_token;
  console.log(access_token);
}
```

Comment: In OP's situation, the values are sent as the form. So I think that in your script, `payload: objectToQueryParams(myPayload)` can be modified to `payload: myPayload`. It seems that at UrlFetchApp, when JSON object is used to `payload`, the value is sent as the form.

Comment: @Tanaike, btw, yes, [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests) does state that one can omit the stringification part. That aaid, I find utilities for creating query strings from objects very useful

Comment: @Oleg Valter Thank you for your comment. From your comment, I could notice that the sample script of UrlFetchApp had been updated. From this situation, I could obtain new information. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Tanaike - my pleasure :) As far as I recall, it was always there, but I am still baffled by the fact that this important info (alongside `JSON.stringify` for JSON payloads) is not in the method description - in my experience (as I am sure in yours) folks skip anything baked into the example